# Is it possible to install XCode 5 on Mac mini?

Tags: xcode, mac-mini, software-update

I have a Mac mini with OS version 10.7.5.

*Software Update* says there are no updates available.

But to install XCode 5 version 10.8.4 is needed.

Is it possible to still install XCode 5 on Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course, it is possible to install Xcode on a maco. But as you said yourself, you need OSX 10.8.4 or newer. So you have to install OSX 10.8.

OSX 10.8 needs an Mac mini **Early 2009 or newer**.

To check how old your mac mini is, follow these instructions:

1. Apple Menu->About this Mac.
2. Click the <kbd>More Info...</kbd>-button.
3. Now you see the year of your mac under the model name.

If your model is able to install it, you can [download mountain lion through the app store](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/os-x-mountain-lion/id537386512?mt=12&ei=Y_BWUsenNq2w4QTF1YD4DQ&usg=AFQjCNFhZkX4ClRmddOYgs3js1y83COqog&sig2=Ku3Wynj8D2bGnrGbt9kTmw&bvm=bv.53760139,d.bGE).